# SwiftUI and functions - Cannot find 'viewContext' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, function, core-data, swiftui

I want to separate my functions from SwiftUI Views. I have this function:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

func deleteAll() {
    let fetchRequestItems: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Item.fetchRequest()
    let deleteRequestItems = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequestItems)
    
    do {
        try viewContext.save()
        try viewContext.execute(deleteRequestItems)
        viewContext.reset()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on 3 lines with **viewContext**:

> Cannot find 'viewContext' in scope

The same function works when it's inside a SwiftUI View. But the views have viewContext injected like this:

```
ContentView()
.environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
```

So the question is:
**How to inject/use Core Data Context (viewContext) inside functions in separate Swift files?**

EDIT:
Persistence.swift is from a SwiftUI 2.0 template and looks like this:

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
        }
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Moneto")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                Typical reasons for an error here include:
                * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                * The device is out of space.
                * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: `deleteAll(context: NSManagedObjectContext) { … }`

Comment: It works! Thanks, @JoakimDanielson :) Can you send it as answer, please, so I could accept it?
2 small comments. 1. It's `deleteAll(viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) { … }` in my case. 2. When I run function, I should use `deleteAll(viewContext: viewContext)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should inject the managed context into your function

```
func deleteAll(viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    //…
}
```

This also gives you the advantage that you can choose which context to delete from if you are working with background or child contexts

Answer (score 0):

Add this var in your view

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have it in views. To be precise, I have: `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext`. But even without `private` it doesn't work.
Please notice that my function is in separate file. Not in a SwiftUI view. It's a Swift file with the function alone.

Comment: No. it's not good. please move your function to your view or view model.

Comment: So I cannot keep them in separate files? What's the proper way to break your view to smaller pieces if you have many functions there?

Comment: use extension. create an extension of your view like ```extension ContentView {...}``` and add this extension in separate file. A global function is not a good idea.

Comment: OK, another idea. This project is from a SwiftUI 2.0 template. It has a Persistence.swift file with PersistenceController struct. When I put this function there, there is no error. Maybe this is a good place for such function?

Comment: You can also make your view context static from Persistence.swift file and then use it everywhere .

Comment: But how to do that?

Comment: Need to check your file. How you added this

Comment: I have edited my question and added Persistence.swift file.

Comment: Try to access like this ```PersistenceController.preview.viewContext```